# C# Decryption with RSA public key returns junk characters

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I need to perform RSA decryption with public key. Following is my code and it's returning junk values after decryption.

**Encryption code**

```
public static string EncryptWithPrivate(byte[] bytes)
    {
        AsymmetricKeyParameter privatekey = null;

        using (var reader = File.OpenText(Path.Combine(Startup.Root, $"Certificates\\private.pem")))
        {
            var keypair = new PemReader(reader).ReadObject() as AsymmetricCipherKeyPair;
            privatekey = keypair.Private;
        }

        try
        {
            var engine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());
            engine.Init(true, privatekey);
            var encryptedBytes = engine.ProcessBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            if (encryptedBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                var encryptedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedBytes);
                return encryptedString;
            }                              
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Log();
            return ex.Message;
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

**Decryption Code**

```
public static string DecryptWithPublic(byte[] bytes)
    {
        AsymmetricKeyParameter publicKey = null;


        using (var privateKeyTextReader = new StringReader(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(Startup.Root, $"Certificates\\public.pem"))))
        {
            publicKey = (AsymmetricKeyParameter)new PemReader(privateKeyTextReader).ReadObject();
        }

        try
        {                              
            var decryptEngine = new Pkcs1Encoding(new RsaEngine());

            decryptEngine.Init(false, publicKey);
            return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptEngine.ProcessBlock(bytes, 0, bytes.Length));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.Log();
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
```

**Test string: "12345678"**

**Output after decryption:** [image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: It must be the padding options.

Comment: @jdweng can you please elaborate more? How should address it?

Comment: First I'm notice you are using ToBase64 string when encrypting but not seeing the opposite when decrypting.I'm suspecting padding but it could be you are loosing some bytes at end of message.  Make sure the length of the encrypted message matches the length of the input to the decrypt method.  And the keys exactly match.  Something is being lost at the end of the message but do not see anything obvious.  The reason I said padding because the default padding when encrypting in Java is different from c#.  So there have been a number of posting when encrypting in java and decrypting in c# failed.

Comment: @jdweng Convert from Base64 is done a step above when passing the byte array into the decrypt function. CryptographyHelper.DecryptWithPublic(Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString)); Also, the code is in C# only. There's no Java.

Comment: If in `DecryptWithPublic` you try to initialize `publicKey` by reading `private.pem` file and using `keypair.Public` - do you still get gibberish output (just to validate that the problem is not with `public.pem` file)?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov Yes. I tried it. Still the result is same.

Comment: How do you generate `bytes` for `EncryptWithPrivate` method? Is it `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes`?

Comment: Also can you try to set `Pkcs1Encoding.StrictLengthEnabled = false;` in the beginning of the app?

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov You are right. There's a custom method to generate data for the byte array which is passed to be encrypted. That array is generating these junk chars. Seems this is not related to encryption and decryption, rather data generation. I'm still debugging. I'll update here accordingly. Thanks for your input.